# Continue execution of parent Dialog in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-online

I have a Dialog in which I've linked a child Dialog. I want to the execution of the Dialog to the parent dialog once my child dialog has completed executing.
How can I achieve this? My child dialog isn't throwing the execution back to the parent Dialog in Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how they work out of the box. When you go to a child you transfer control to child and the parent ends.

You could look to rearrange your dialog;so the last step of the child, is to start the parent as a child dialog. The parent dialog would then need to somehow skip to the right page. Or it might be easier to break the parent dialog into multiple parts, which are chained together using start child.